# If a value in a cell has a duplicate within same column, delete both cells

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

What I want to happen is if a value on Sheet1 exists in Sheet2, I want them both to delete. Essentially, i want a list of cells that do not exist in both sheets. I have queried an array that combines two columns on different sheets. I am just stumped on how to delete both cells (automatically) if they exist twice.

For reference, the first sheet has a list of incoming product's serial numbers, The second sheets has a list of those same products that are now going out. I want an active list of what i have in-house.

[Sheet one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WEui.png)

[Sheet two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x82VG.png)

[Sheet three combining the both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXvUp.png)

Comment: Do you want to retain sheets 1 and 2 as-is, and create your "stock" list on a third sheet? Or putting it another way, when you say "delete" do you mean physically delete them from sheets 1 & 2, or simply ensure that they don't appear on sheet 3?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work

```
=query({incoming!B:B, outgoing!C:C}, "select Col1 where Col1 <> Col2",0)
```

- Assume we have an 'incoming' sheet for incoming products, and 'outgoing' sheet for outgoing products.
- Assume we want to list on 'stock', all the stock that has come in, but has not gone out - in effect a list of the stock on hand.

The formula is entered anywhere in the "stock" sheet.

---

Layout of the "incoming" sheet
[image: Incoming]

---

Layout of the "outgoing" sheet
[image: Outgoing]

---

Results in the "Stock" sheet
[image: Stock sheet]

---

The query uses curly brackets to group together two arrays. This is described (albeit briefly, in [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

The stock codes on the "incoming" sheet will include all products, regardless of whether they are outgoing, or they are still on hand. So we compare the codes in this array to the "outgoing" codes and apply the criterion of "where Col1 <> Col2". That is, where the code is in 'incoming" but not in "outgoing".